# Use Tomcats configured Executors in Application Code?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, executorservice

Tomcat (6) allows the definition of threadpools in the [Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html) Element in server.xml . Is it possible to use such a threadpool as [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) within the application code? Of course, I can create my own threadpools in Servlets / ServletContextListener / Spring / whatever, but it seems nicer to me to have the configuration of the number of threads etc. in the deployment descriptor.

Update: my idea was to configure a separate executor element and only use this threadpool within the application but not in tomcats own components. This way it would probably not interfere with tomcat itself.

Answer (score 2):

Why should we be afraid and not to use the tomcat executor?

It is called executor! not something else. Ideally, once an ExecutorService is configured w.r.t the number of CPU cores, then all programs should use the same executor service if all the codes are in asynchronous mode. Given not all codes are in asynchronous mode so use a much larger number relative to CPU cores. Anyway, there is no point for every component to use their own executor services.

How often you write a piece of code with dead loop in it?

So from a webapp, how do we access the executor used by servlet container such as tomcat?

One solution should be specify a custom executor and replace the default org.apache.catalina.core.StandardExecutor in server.xml, then webapps can access it even through a static variable since this executor is customized.